# Django CRUD app example/plugin for consuming external REST API?

Tags: django, api

I have just started to learn django. I don't need to Create and API e.g. I will NOT be using Django REST Framework. Are there any best practice or django plugin app which shows you how to consume external REST API in a best practice manner? My goal is to create CRUD like application using/consuming external REST API? Any suggestions?

Comment: Django is about writing back-end and writing APIs. Why would you not write an API (or back-end) in Django and prefer to consume API which should be done by some front-end framework like Vue, Angular etc.

Comment: The API I want to use - throttle requests per min as well as total request per day. How can I solve this in front-end? is there a way to cache in front-end framework such as Vue?